# "Recursive indexing failed at level 4" R code

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, outer-join

I have a list named PDay which contains 3 sublists. Each sublist contains 6 data frames.
In order to print every data frames ( PDay[[1]][[1]], PDay[[1]][[2]] , ...), I worte the following code:

```
    A<-seq_len(3)
    B<-seq_len(6)
    F1<-function(x,y){
      PDay[[y]][[x]]
    }
    c(outer(B,A,F1))
```

This is my error:
"Recursive indexing failed at level 4"

What's wrong with my code? How can i correct it?

Thanks

EDIT: no nested loops please. Just outer() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `outer` to succeed one needs to have a function that is vectorized at the very least in x. The "[[" function cannot be used to deliver a vectorized result. This approach was tested on a smaller example that you specified but should be sufficiently general:

```
F1<-function(x,y){
       print( PDay[[y]][[x]] )
     }
 VF1 <- Vectorize(F1)
 outer(B,A,VF1)
```

When you run it you will notice that you first see the printed results of the dataframes and then a matrix of lists. If you wanted that matrix result suppressed, you could assign it to a name as part of the call to outer (using the VF1 function only for it's printing side effect) and then `rm(the_name)`.

```
  junk_name=outer(B,A,VF1)
  rm(junk_name)
```

And another way to suppress the output of `outer` while getting the printing side-effects is with the `invisible` function:

```
 invisible( outer(B,A,VF1) )
```

Comment: Can you please show me how you suppose to suppress the matrix in term of code?

Comment: Thanks, however I tried using invisible but it gives me the error:

Comment: Error in dim(robj) <- c(dX, dY) : 
  dims [product 18] do not match the length of object [36]

Comment: As if there was still a matrix . Why this?

Comment: Post `dput(PDay)`

Comment: I tried applying dput(PDay[[y]][[x]]) inside the F1 function and in an other case I try recalling the main list PDay<-dput(PDay).

Comment: No. I wasn't suggesting you do some in code with the resutls I was suggesting that you post _in_ _your_ _question_ the results of that call so that we had a [MCVE].

Comment: Damn! Thanks for your patience, I am new here! Now I have a look how to do it! Meanwhile I can tell you that each of the 3 sublists has 6 dataframes with different number of rows each (one of them also has 0 rows). Supposing this information may be helpful

Comment: However, now I absolutely go learn how to dput(). Sorry for my newbie answers!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
print(PDay)
```

Or if the goal is to use a different function, you can double-lapply:

```
lapply(PDay, function(x) lapply(x, print))
```